# “The user denied permission to use Service Worker.” при использовании codespace или vscode web

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ошибка при использование VSCode Web или GitHub.dev/codespace
[image: ошибка vscode web]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас, как и у меня, включена настройка "Блокировать сторонние файлы cookie". Мне удалось обойти ошибку, добавив [*.]github.dev в "Сайты, которые всегда могут использовать cookies" с установленным флажком "Включить сторонние cookies на этом сайте".